# R CMD check Undocumented Functions Warning with Registration

Tags: c, r, warnings, package

I was recently trying to update the package simest on CRAN and realized I need to register native routines. I somehow managed this and when I run R CMD check simest, I get a warning that the C functions do not have documentation. I am not sure why this happened?

```
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>
#include "simest.h"

static R_NativePrimitiveArgType derivcvxpec_t[] = {
    INTSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP
};

static R_NativePrimitiveArgType cpen_t[] = {
   INTSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP,
   REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP,
   INTSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, INTSXP, REALSXP
};

static R_NativePrimitiveArgType predcvxpen_t[] = {
   INTSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP,
   REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP
};

static R_NativePrimitiveArgType spen_egcv_t[] = {
    INTSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP,
    REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, INTSXP, INTSXP, REALSXP
};

static R_NativePrimitiveArgType penta_t[] = {
   INTSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP,
   REALSXP, REALSXP, REALSXP
};

static const R_CMethodDef cMethods[] = {
   {"derivcvxpec", (DL_FUNC) &derivcvxpec, 5, derivcvxpec_t},
   {"cpen", (DL_FUNC) &cpen, 16, cpen_t},
   {"predcvxpen", (DL_FUNC) &predcvxpen, 11, predcvxpen_t},
   {"spen_egcv", (DL_FUNC) &spen_egcv, 11, spen_egcv_t},
   {"penta", (DL_FUNC) &penta, 8, penta_t},
   {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

void R_init_simest(DllInfo *dll)
{
   R_registerRoutines(dll, cMethods, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

The header file simest.h just contains the C function definitions. The warnings I got from the R CMD check are as follows:

```
* checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented code objects:
  'cpen' 'derivcvxpec' 'penta' 'predcvxpen' 'spen_egcv'
All user-level objects in a package should have documentation entries.
See chapter 'Writing R documentation files' in the 'Writing R
Extensions' manual.
```

These are all C functions. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The error makes it seems like you don't have any documentation for those function. Did you attempt to document those functions in any way in your package? You need a help page to describe what the function does and what parameters it expects, etc.

Comment: You are not misunderstanding the question. The warning is for no documentation for C function not R functions. I had documentation for R functions. C functions are written to be called using .C. They are not intended for user of the package. It is not common for R CMD check to give warning for C function documentation.

Comment: I still think it has to do with where you referring to these functions in the R code, not the C code you are showing here. Maybe you need `?suppressForeignCheck` to mask those keywords in your R code.